# IBM Bluemix IoT Watson service Driver Behaviour

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, iot-for-automotive, iot-driver-behavior

I want to explore and use the driver behavior service in my application. Unfortunately I got stuck as I'm getting empty response from getAnalyzedTripSummary API instead Trip UUID.

Here are the steps I've followed.

- I've added the services called Driver behavior and Context Mapping to my application @Bluemix.
- Pushed multiple sample data packets to the Driver Behavior using "sendCarProbe" API
- Sent Job Request using "sendJobRequest" API with from and to dates as post data.
- Tried "getJobInfo" API, which results the status of job "job_status" : "SUCCEEDED")
- Tried "getAnalyzedTripSummaryList" to get trip_uuid. But
  its resulting empty. []

Could someone help me to understand what's wrong and why I'm getting empty response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your procedure is OK.

There are following possibilities not to get valid analysis result.

(1) In current Driving Behavior Analysis, it requires at least 10 valid gps points within a trip (trip_id) on a vehicle (trip_id). Please check your data which is used on "sendCarProbe" API.

(2) Please check "sendJobRequest" API's from and to date (yyyy-mm-dd) really matches with your car probe timestamp.